# Label a HalfLine

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to show the two accumulation points of the attached plot with two HalfLines, but I don't know how to label the HalfLines. I've been searching quite a while on internet but I can't find a useful hint.

---

**Data**

```
data3 = {0.5`, 0.75`, 0.5625`, 0.73828125`, 0.5796661376953125`,
    0.7309599195141345`, 0.5899725467340735`, 0.7257148225025549`, 
   0.5971584567079203`, 0.7216807028704055`, 0.6025729979246489`, 
   0.7184363402902498`, 0.6068566957218066`, 0.7157449397382518`, 
   0.6103623629320143`, 0.713460446544187`, 0.6133039132834688`, 
   0.7114866697039566`, 0.6158201656125887`, 0.7097570677124175`, 
   0.6180059176340649`, 0.7082238102100269`, 0.6199285345848561`, 
   0.706851439776987`, 0.6216374455865626`, 0.7056129954935281`, 
   0.6231698882525353`, 0.7044875358835738`, 0.6245545430047923`, 
   0.7034584974506021`, 0.6258139194454301`, 0.7025125730213365`, 
   0.6269659733048335`, 0.701638924868269`, 0.6280252319339057`, 
   0.7008286199648089`, 0.6290035962090911`, 0.7000742164953654`, 
   0.629910923681297`, 0.6993694557248167`, 0.630755460371971`, 
   0.6987090287487417`, 0.6315441656811952`, 0.6980883974257147`, 
   0.6322829604159362`, 0.6975036551507876`, 0.6329769186062363`, 
   0.6969514173539713`, 0.6336304176067855`, 0.6964287344707083`, 
   0.6342472568227079`, 0.6959330221067338`, 0.6348307525443665`, 
   0.6954620045049594`, 0.6353838143847096`, 0.6950136684079395`, 
   0.6359090074022347`, 0.694586225120818`, 0.6364086029796909`, 
   0.6941780790993871`, 0.6368846207918165`, 0.6937878017720418`, 
   0.6373388636530795`, 0.6934141095914426`, 0.6377729466328484`, 
   0.6930558455283068`, 0.6381883215220516`, 0.6927119633847543`, 
   0.6385862975051794`, 0.6923815144314178`, 0.6389680587152226`, 
   0.6920636359707674`, 0.6393346792130657`, 0.6917575415057763`, 
   0.6396871358269814`, 0.6914625122533633`, 0.6400263192048922`, 
   0.691177889789789`, 0.6403530433665698`, 0.6909030696532253`, 
   0.6406680539909273`, 0.6906374957592167`, 0.6409720356319639`, 
   0.6903806555093409`, 0.641265618023501`, 0.6901320754933149`, 
   0.6415493816058132`, 0.6898913177010356`, 0.6418238623852931`, 
   0.6896579761743524`, 0.6420895562203462`, 0.6894316740393153`, 
   0.6423469226119878`, 0.6892120608686902`, 0.6425963880654693`, 
   0.6889988103320462`, 0.6428383490792137`, 0.6887916180969741`, 
   0.6430731748089789`, 0.6885901999502382`, 0.6433012094481876`, 
   0.68839429011206`, 0.643522774359519`, 0.6882036397204397`, 
   0.6437381699879368`, 0.688018015465557`, 0.6439476775811808`, 
   0.6878371983569533`, 0.6441515607402317`, 0.6876609826084659`, 
   0.6443500668192752`}
```

**Code**

```
ListLinePlot[data3, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 4}, ImageSize -> Full, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin }, AxesLabel -> {"n", ""}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black, Bold}, 
 Epilog -> {Black, Dashed, HalfLine[{0, 0.64435006681}, {1, 0}],  
   HalfLine[{0, 0.6876609826085}, {1, 0}]}]
```

Here is the plot so far

[image: First 110 iterations]

Comment: Please post the `data3`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Try within Epilog: `Black, Text["ABCD", {xcoord, 0.65}]` and adjust the `xcoord`/ycoord values accordingly. If this is not what you are looking for, then edit the post further

Comment: @Syed thanks this is what I was looking for. With this I could also adjust the size of the text:
Epilog -> {Black, Text[Style["x_1", Bold, Medium], {-0.1, 0.64}], , 
  Dashed, HalfLine[{0, 0.64435006681}, {1, 0}]}